# kdbg assembly, how to display flags?

Tags: assembly, kdbg

How to display **flags list** in Kdbg.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have kdbg, but the [manual](http://www.kdbg.org/manual/registers.html) says:

> To display this window, choose View|Registers. The column Decoded value displays the contents of the registers in a decoded form. [...] the flag registers are sometimes decoded into named flags.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom-left of the Kdbg there are five tabs. Select Registers and scroll down to see the flags.